# Unable to refactor using LINQ to Entities and LinqKit / PredicateBuilder

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, expression-trees, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I have been trying to refactor a LINQ expression into a method, and have been running into both the "`Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.`" and "`The parameter 'xyz' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.`" exceptions.

Here are the relevant parts of the entity model (using EF 4.2 / LINQ to Entities):

```cs
public class Place : Entity
{
    public string OfficialName { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PlaceName> { get; protected internal set; }
}

public class PlaceName : Entity
{
    public string Text { get; protected internal set; }
    public string AsciiEquivalent { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual Language TranslationTo { get; protected internal set; }
}

public class Language : Entity
{
    public string TwoLetterIsoCode { get; protected internal set; }
}
```

The basic relational model is this:

```
Place (1) <-----> (0..*) PlaceName (0..*) <-----> (0..1) Language
```

I am trying to create a query which will, when given a search `term`, try to find `Place` entities whose `OfficialName` starts with the `term` OR who has a `PlaceName` whose `Text` or `AsciiEquivalent` starts with the search `term`. (`Language` isn't where I'm having trouble, though it is part of the query, because `PlaceName`s should only match for the `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterIsoLanguageName`.)

The following code **does work**:

```cs
internal static IQueryable<Place> WithName(this IQueryable<Place> queryable, 
    string term)
{
    var matchesName = OfficialNameMatches(term)
        .Or(NonOfficialNameMatches(term));
    return queryable.AsExpandable().Where(matchesName);
}

private static Expression<Func<Place, bool>> OfficialNameMatches(string term)
{
    return place => place.OfficialName.StartsWith(term);
}

private static Expression<Func<Place, bool>> NonOfficialNameMatches(string term)
{
    var currentLanguage = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    return place => place.Names.Any(
        name =>
        name.TranslationToLanguage != null
        &&
        name.TranslationToLanguage.TwoLetterIsoCode == currentLanguage
        &&
        (
            name.Text.StartsWith(term)
            ||
            (
                name.AsciiEquivalent != null
                &&
                name.AsciiEquivalent.StartsWith(term)
            )
        )
    );
}
```

What I am trying to do next is refactor the `NonOfficialNameMatches` method to extract the `name => ...` expression out into a separate method, so that it can be reused by other queries. Here is one example I have tried, which **does not work** and throws the exception "`The parameter 'place' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.`":

```cs
private static Expression<Func<Place, bool>> NonOfficialNameMatches(string term)
{
    return place => place.Names.AsQueryable().AsExpandable()
        .Any(PlaceNameMatches(term));
}

public static Expression<Func<PlaceName, bool>> PlaceNameMatches(string term)
{
    var currentLanguage = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    return name =>
            name.TranslationToLanguage != null
            &&
            name.TranslationToLanguage.TwoLetterIsoCode == currentLanguage
            &&
            (
                name.Text.StartsWith(term)
                ||
                (
                    name.AsciiEquivalent != null
                    &&
                    name.AsciiEquivalent.StartsWith(term)
                )
            );
}
```

When I don't have the `.AsExpandable()` chain in `NonOfficialNameMatches`, then I get the "`Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.`" exception.

I have followed [other advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957283/304832) such as several combinations of invoking `.Expand()` on the predicates, but always end up with one of the aforementioned exceptions.

**Is it even possible to factor out this expression into a separate method using LINQ to Entities with LinqKit / PredicateBuilder?** If so, how? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method below should work:

```cs
private static Expression<Func<Place, bool>> NonOfficialNameMatches(string term)
{
    Expression<Func<PlaceName, bool>> placeNameExpr = PlaceNameMatches(term);
    Expression<Func<Place, bool>> placeExpr =
        place => place.Names.Any(name => placeNameExpr.Invoke(name));
    return placeExpr.Expand();
}
```

EDIT:  Adding additional explanations

The `PlaceNameMatches` method works as you wrote it.  Your issues were in how you used the method.  If you want to factor out parts of an expression follow the 3 steps I did in the method above.

1. Set a local variable to the expression created by a method.
2. Set another local variable to a new expression that Invokes the local variable expression.
3. Call the LinkKit `Expand` method: this will expand any Invoked expressions

Comment: +100, thank you I was beginning to think this question would never get answered. The additional explanation helps too.