# Nesting PredicateBuilder predicates : 'The parameter 'f' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression'

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, linqkit

I am building predicates using LinqKit's **PrediateBuilder class** to dynamically setup filters and **I want to combine a nested one to another**.

I have read this (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
// The main predicate.
var mainPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Document>();

// ... some other conditions to the main predicate here ...

// The inner predicate (combined conditions using OR).
var innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Document>();

foreach (var period in periods)
{
    var p = period;
    innerPredicate =
        innerPredicate.Or(
            d =>
            (d.Date >= p.DateFrom && d.Date <= p.DateTo));
}

mainPredicate = mainPredicate.And(innerPredicate);

documents = this.ObjectSet.AsExpandable().Where(mainPredicate).ToList();
```

I am combining my two predicates just like it is explained in the documentation. However, I get this exception :

> The parameter 'f' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities
>   query expression

I first thought that the inner predicate has to be expanded before combining it with the main predicate, so I changed my combining code to add a call to to the inner predicate's `Expand` method like this :

```
mainPredicate = mainPredicate.And(innerPredicate.Expand());
```

**But I get the exact same exception.**

The only difference in my code versus the documentation is that I dynamically build my nested predicate **using a `foreach` loop**. I just don't know how it can negatively affect the resulting expression.

- What is wrong with my code ?
- How can I actually debug this ?
- Where the *f* parameter comes from ? How is it generated ? Why is it problematic in my case ?
- Is there some kind of expression tree visualizer of some kind that could help me actually see what is wrong with the resulting expression ? Because the expression's body is hard to read.

Comment: Looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947820/c-sharp-predicatebuilder-entities-the-parameter-f-was-not-bound-in-the-specif) it appears you might have to use `Expand()` inside the `Or` of the `innerPredicate` as well

Comment: I have tried it. I get the same exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I have found a way to avoid combining multiple predicates to the main expression tree.

Given that each predicate represents a different filter and I want the final, combined filter to be a series of *must-be-respected* conditions, we can say that each of the predicates has to return **true** for the final predicate to return true.

For that to work, the predicates has to be combined with **`AND`**. So, the resulting SQL query must look like this :

`predicate1 AND predicate2 AND predicate3` ...

A better way to combine these predicates with `AND` is to chain `Where` query operators to the final query, like this :

```
var documents = this.ObjectSet.AsExpandable()
    .Where(mainPredicate)
    .Where(otherPredicate)
    .Where(yetAnotherPredicate)
    .ToList();
```

The resulting SQL query will combine each of these predicates with `AND`. That is just what I wanted to do.

It is easier than hacking out an expression tree by myself.